# Getting Error While Using setText in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i am getting error while using the values in my code.It says can not resolve the symbol setText.

[image]

```
protected void showRecords() {
            if(c!=null && c.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    String Starter = c.getString(1);
                    Starter.setText=c.getString(1);
                    String MainCourse = c.getString(1);
                    MainCource.setText(MainCourse);
                    String Dessert = c.getString(1);
                    Dessert.setText=c.getString(1);

                }while(c.moveToNext());
            }
```

Comment: You can´t set a text on a String object....You definitely need basics on programming...

Answer (score 0):

if `Starter` is a string then you would assign to it directly:
`Starter = c.getString(1);`

Also, you should follow Java naming conventions. Variables should not start with an Uppercase in order to distinguish them easily from a Type. So you should declare it like this:

`String starter = c.getString(1);`

Once you do that. There's not reason to call setText() on it. Unless you have some component (that is not a string) where you want to set the value on.

Comment: in it i am getting error in starter line and in dessert line MainCourse is working String Starter = c.getString(1);
                Starter.setText(Starter);
                String MainCourse = c.getString(1);
                MainCource.setText(MainCourse);
                String Dessert = c.getString(1);
                Dessert.setText(Dessert);

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see you don´t get what we suggest you. So let me explain it step by step. This is your code:

```
String Starter = c.getString(1);
Starter.setText=c.getString(1);
String MainCourse = c.getString(1);
MainCource.setText(MainCourse);
String Dessert = c.getString(1);
Dessert.setText=c.getString(1);
```

These lines are wrong:

```
Starter.setText=c.getString(1);
MainCource.setText(MainCourse);
Dessert.setText=c.getString(1);
```

`Starter`, `MainCourse` and `Dessert` are objects of type `String`. Strings are texts and you can´t set text on a text. I guess, what you want to do is to set a text on a `TextView`.

So what you need is a `TextView`. This must be in your layout xml file. For example, it can look like this:

```
 <TextView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
   android:id="@+id/dessertView"/>
```

Then, in your activity, you have to make a global object:

```
private TextView mDessertTextView;
```

initialize it in `onCreate()`:

```
mDessertTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dessertView);
```

Then you retrieve the text like you did here:

```
String Dessert = c.getString(1);
```

and this String called `Dessert`, you have to set to that `TextView`:

```
mDessertView.setText(Dessert);
```

That´s the way it works. You really need some basics on programming, you should start by zero:

[Basic Example](http://android4beginners.com/2013/06/lesson-1-3-how-to-modify-textview-in-java-code-findviewbyid-settext-and-gettext-methods/)